# Angular directive own scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I have the following directive

```
<preload loaded="false" ng-if="!loaded"></preload>

return {

            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'template.html',
            scope: {
                loaded: '='
            },


            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {        
                //scope.loaded = true
                //hide directive
            }

        }
```

Outside any controller.

My question is, can I change the loaded to true inside the link function and the directive will dissapear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean change the value via some action like clicking a button? If so:

I think you could toggle that value in the same way you would any other value. A fourth parameter that can be passed is the controller.

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
  scope.loaded = true;
  scope.toggle = function() {
    scope.loaded = !scope.loaded;
  };
}
```

And then you can assign the `scope.toggle` to a button. Or do you mean just change the value when the link function is run?

**EDIT**

Here's a quick plunkr demonstrating what you mean written for angular 1.5:

https://plnkr.co/edit/6nj4N6LdGULv7vX4EUqs?p=preview

**EDIT 2**
Lines 13-20 of my plunkr:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('PreloadCtrl',PreloadCtrl);

  function PreloadCtrl() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.loaded = false;
  }
```

This basically defines a controller called **PreloadCtrl** and passes it a function which acts as the controller. This is the same as doing this, which is probably what you're used to:

```
.controller('PreloadCtrl', function () {//Controller stuff})
```

Comment: No, I mean my directive its outside a controller, how can I use ng-if on itself?

Comment: like <directive ng-if="!hide"></directive> and in link: function() { //make hide=true }

Comment: @Hiero directives are always outside of controllers. So you mean the link property controls whether or not the directive appears then?

Comment: yes, but I dont want to use display:none or something, I want ng-if

Comment: @Hiero ok - np - what version of angular are you using?

Comment: angular 1.5.x latest

Comment: Then you shouldn't be using directive. You should be using component. You don't need to use link for what you want

Comment: I'm prepping a quick plunkr to show you what I mean just for reference

Comment: are you using same controller for the App?

Comment: No - that controller is dedicated to the preload component and is only used for it

Comment: I dont understand the line 13-16, angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('PreloadCtrl',PreloadCtrl);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104652/discussion-between-hiero-and-katana24).